# Error ejecutando docker build -t en Windows 10

Tags: docker

Estoy intentando compilar en Windows 10 una imagen con Docker (creo, todavía no sé mucho del tema) con el comando `docker build -t getting-started .` y aparece el siguiente log con el error:

```
[+] Building 8.2s (12/15)
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                   0.0s 
 => => transferring dockerfile: 32B                                                                                    0.0s 
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                      0.0s 
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                        0.0s 
 => resolve image config for docker.io/docker/dockerfile:1                                                             2.0s 
 => [auth] docker/dockerfile:pull token for registry-1.docker.io                                                       0.0s 
 => CACHED docker-image://docker.io/docker/dockerfile:1@sha256:42399d4635eddd7a9b8a24be879d2f9a930d0ed040a61324cfdf59  0.0s 
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                      0.0s 
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                   0.0s 
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/node:12-alpine                                                      1.1s 
 => [auth] library/node:pull token for registry-1.docker.io                                                            0.0s 
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                      0.0s 
 => => transferring context: 2.49kB                                                                                    0.0s 
 => CACHED [1/5] FROM docker.io/library/node:12-alpine@sha256:1ecf7789a48e604a841409e65cf2e172d5a014ecd5e60689137d785  0.0s 
 => ERROR [2/5] RUN apk add --no-cache python g++ make                                                            4.6s

------
 > [2/5] RUN apk add --no-cache python g++ make:
#11 0.368 fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.14/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
#11 1.910 fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.14/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
#11 4.561 ERROR: unable to select packages:
#11 4.603   python (no such package):
#11 4.603     required by: world[python]
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c apk add --no-cache python g++ make]: exit code: 1
```

Este es el contenido de mi Dockerfile:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM node:12-alpine
RUN apk add --no-cache python g++ make
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN yarn install --production
CMD ["node", "src/index.js"]
```

Estoy siguiendo la guía **Sample application** de Docker:
https://docs.docker.com/get-started/02_our_app/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para instalar python en alpine tienes que indicar la versión de python que necesitas.

**Python3**

```
RUN apk add --no-cache python3 g++ make
```

**Python2**

```
RUN apk add --no-cache python2 g++ make
```

Comment: Excelente, funcionó. Muchas gracias.

Comment: De nada amigo..